# Queing threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm using queue implementation from the bottom of [Queue doc page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), and I have a couple of questions:

1. There are 50 threads and they fetch hundreds of thousands of JSON files. Is it a good idea to set `Queue(maxsize=` to twice the number of threads, or perhaps it should be more or less?
2. I want to put `worker` function in a different module. How would I go about it? When I try to do that, I get `NameError: global name 'q' is not defined` in the  `item = q.get()` line of the function; adding `global q` to the function doesn't help.

**Edit**: Is it possible to move worker function to another module with minimal changes to that code? I don't really understand objects that well, and I'd prefer to keep the code as simple as possible.

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()
```

Comment: Weather you need to set maxsize depends on how you fill your Queue and if you are storing the data or just references in the Queue. I would set maxsize as a function of Queue memory footprint instead of thread count. If you really have hundreds of thousands of Queue items with small memory footprint (e.g. a string with a filename) you should set it high enough so your queue won't run out of items. I use 1000 in such cases.

Comment: If you want to make use of multiple processors you should use the multiprocessing Queue module by the way.
For example here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/03/python-concurrency-porting-from-a-queue-to-multiprocessing/

Comment: Is it going to improve performance in any way? I assumed the main bottleneck is net latency. And queue items are just long integers.

Comment: It all depends on the specifics of your application.
I just wanted to point out, that you won't be using more than one cpu core at a given moment in time if you stick with the Queue module. This might be tolerable for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,inputQueue,inputLock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.inputQueue=inputQueue
        self.inputLock=inputLock          

    def run(self):       
        while True:
            if not self.inputQueue.empty():
                self.inputLock.acquire()
                item=self.inputQueue.get()
                self.inputLock.release()
        #process item
                self.inputQueue.task_done()
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

class Main():

    def __init__(self):
        self.workersQueue = Queue.Queue()
        self.workersLock = threading.RLock()
        self.workers = list()

        #start threads
        for index in range(10):            
            self.uploaders.append(Worker(self.workersQueue, self.workersLock))
            self.uploaders[index].start()

        self.workersQueue.join()
```

Here worker is a class(a thread , to which the queue is shared ).
A main class is used to create workers and thereby to load the data required for the worker threads.

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: It is not necessary to use the lock. `Queue.Queue` implements its operations thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll give it a try as a last resort.